# C multidimentional char array - assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory-management, char

I create a big 2d char array and want to assign strings to it.

```
int i;
char **word;
int start_size = 35000;
word=(char **) malloc(start_size*sizeof(char *));
for(i=0;i<start_size;i++)
    word[i]=(char *) malloc(start_size*sizeof(char));

word[2][2] = "word";
```

how do I assign a string?
Explain me why this code doesn't work...
I am new to low level programming and C but experienced in high level programming

Comment: `strcpy(word[2], "word");`

Comment: read about pointer and arrays. your question is very basic

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do string assignment in C.

You need to call a function, sepcifically `strcpy()` (prototype in `<string.h>`)

```
#include <string.h>

strcpy(word[2], "word");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide if you want a list of strings or a 2D array of strings.

---

A list of string works like this:

```
char **word;
word = (char**)malloc(start_size*sizeof(char*));
word[2] = "word";
```

In this example `word[2]` would be the third string in the list and `word[2][1]` would be the second character in the third string.

---

If you want a 2D array of string you have to do this:

```
int i;
char ***word;
     ^^^ 3 stars
int start_size = 35000;
word = (char***)malloc(start_size*sizeof(char**));
            ^^^ 3 stars                        ^^^ 2 stars
for(i=0;i<start_size;i++)
    word[i] = (char**) malloc(start_size*sizeof(char*));
                   ^^^ 2 stars                     ^^^ 1 star

word[2][2] = "word"; // no it works!
```

---

Note that in C you do not need the casts before the `malloc`. So this would also work:

```
word = malloc(start_size*sizeof(char**));
```

Comment: if you a assign a string like "word", then you can't modify later

Comment: Why the downvote? Please comment so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
word[2][2] = "word";
```

In the above statement, the string literal `"word"` is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element which has type `char *` whereas `word[2][2]` has type `char`. This attempts to assign a pointer to a character. This explains the warning message you have stated -

```
assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

You can use string literals only to initialize character arrays. What you need to do is use the standard function `strcpy` to copy the string literal. Also, you should not cast the result of `malloc`. Please read this -  [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1809377) I suggest the following changes -

```
int i;
int start_size = 35000;

// do not cast the result of malloc
char **word = malloc(start_size * sizeof *word);

// check word for NULL in case malloc fails 
// to allocate memory

for(i = 0; i < start_size; i++) {
    // do not cast the result of malloc. Also, the
    // the sizeof(char) is always 1, so you don't need
    // to specify it, just the number of characters 
    word[i] = malloc(start_size);

    // check word[i] for NULL in case malloc
    // malloc fails to allocate memory
}

// copy the string literal "word" to the 
// buffer pointed to by word[2]
strcpy(word[2], "word");
```